# Are there more difference between All Might / One for All quirk and Re-Destro quirks other than how the power is accumulated?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So both All Might / Re-Destro had/has quirks which stores power, though how the power is stored is different, one he stores accumulated power from him/his former users, and the other stores power by converting anger and frustation into power. Then both quirks allow them to increase their strenghts and speeds.

Are there more difference between All Might / One for All quirk and Re-Destro quirk, other than how the power is accumulated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chapter 213, many difference between One for All and Stress are shown. Spoilers for the chapter:

> 1. The chapter shows that Deku can communicate with former users of One for All. This was foreshadowed in previous chapters. It is this link with former users that allow him to break out of brainwashing, something Re-Destro has not been shown to do. 2. One for All not only stores power, it also stores the abilities of previous users, allowing Deku to access abilities such as Blackwhip. This allows for a versatile skill set beyond speed and strength.

More differences may appear in the future, but these are differences that are known for now.